# Jquery - How to add unique id to generated ul's so they can be deleted uniquely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following problem. On a button click I generate this inside a `div`:

```
<ul id="">
    <li><input type="text" class="small" name="call_letters" maxlength="5" value="{{ Input::old("call_letters") }}" /></li>

    <li>
        <select name="am_fm" class="vsmall">
            <option value="1" @if(Input::old('am_pm') == 1) {{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>AM</option>
            <option value="2" @if(Input::old('am_pm') == 2) {{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>PM</option>
        </select>
    </li>

    <li>
        <select name="station_state" style="margin-left:-14px" class="vsmall">
            @foreach($states as $s)
                <option value="{{ $s->id }}" @if(Input::old('station_state') == $s->id) {{ 'selected="selected"' }}@endif>{{ $s->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </li>

    <li><input type="text" class="small" style="margin-left:-15px;" name="wattage" maxlength="6" value="{{ Input::old("wattage")  }}" /></li>

    <li>
        <select name="programming_format" id="programming_format" >
            @foreach($programming_format as $pf)
                <option value="{{ $pf->id  }}" @if(Input::old('programming_format') == $pf->id ) {{ 'selected="selected"' }} @endif>{{ $pf->name  }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </li>

    <li><input type="text" class="small" name="transmission_city" maxlength="20" value="{{ Input::old('transmission_city') }}" /></li>

    <li>
        <select name="major_metropolitan_area" id="major_metropolitan_area">
            @foreach($metropolitan_area as $ma)
                <option value="{{ $ma->id }}" @if(Input::old('major_metropolitan_area') == $ma->id ) {{ 'selected="selected"' }} @endif>{{ $ma->name  }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </li>

    <li><button class="simulcast">Simulcast</button></li>
    <li><button class="remove_station">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

**This is the JS code:**

```
$("#add_station").click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: advoke.base_url+"/new-vendor-user/station/ajax",
        type: "post",
        datatype: "html",
        data: '',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#ajax-loading').show();
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#ajax-loading').hide();
        $("#station").append(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('No response from server');
    });
    return false;
});
}); //<--THIS DOES NOT BELONG HERE, IT'S ONE TO MANY (note from editor - myfunkyside)
```

What all of this code does, is generating the `ul` from above when an add-button is pressed. Each `ul` has some inputs inside and a delete-button.
What I want is, when the delete-button from a `ul` is pressed, the `ul` is to be removed. Thing is, I don't know how to create a unique ID for each `ul` so that I know which one to give to the remove function.

Comment: You don't need a unique id for each `<ul>`. You can instead use `$(this).closest('ul')` from the button's click handler to get to the `<ul>`

Comment: I've tried $(this).closest('ul').remove(); but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need ID's at all. Using *jQuery* you can find the parent `ul` relative to each clicked delete-button. Use this:

```
$("#station").on("click",".remove_station",function(){
    $(this).closest("ul").remove(); //find the first <ul> up the DOM tree
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the following line to manually go up two levels in the DOM tree (to the `ul`):

```
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //go two levels up the DOM tree to the <ul>
```

Notice that I use `$("#station").on("click",".remove_station",function(){` (*delegated event*),
instead of `$(".remove_station").click(function(){` (*direct event*).
This is necessary because **event handlers are bound only to the elements that exist on the page at the time that the event handler is created** *([read this for more info](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events))*.

- So when you use the direct event handler, only the elements with class `.remove_station` that *already exist on the page* when that event handler is created, will execute the function to remove the `ul`.
- But when you use the delegated event handler, the event handler is bound to `#station`. So now when you click a delete-button, `#station` registers the event, and from there it searches the element that caused the event. This way your event handler will also work on `ul`s that are added *after* the event handler was created (as long as `#station` existed at that time).

See example:

```js
$("#station").on("click",".remove_station",function(){
  $(this).closest("ul").remove(); //find the first <ul> up the DOM tree
  //$(this).parent().parent().remove(); //go two levels up the DOM tree to the <ul>
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="station">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="text" class="small" name="call_letters" maxlength="5" value="something" /></li>

    <li>
      <select name="am_fm" class="vsmall">
        <option value="1">AM</option>
        <option value="2">PM</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li>
      <select name="station_state" style="margin-left:-14px" class="vsmall">
        <option value="something">something</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li><input type="text" class="small" style="margin-left:-15px;" name="wattage" maxlength="6" value="something" /></li>

    <li>
      <select name="programming_format" id="programming_format" >
        <option value="something">something</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li><input type="text" class="small" name="transmission_city" maxlength="20" value="something" /></li>

    <li>
      <select name="major_metropolitan_area" id="major_metropolitan_area">
        <option value="something">something</option>
      </select>
    </li>

    <li><button class="simulcast">Simulcast</button></li>
    <li><button class="remove_station">Delete</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgwtcvsj/1/**)

This really is more effective and flexible than using unique ID's.

---

But if you really want to use a unique ID, I would do it like this:

```
<button class="remove_station" onclick="remove('id#1')">Delete</button>
```

- `onclick="remove('id#1')"` calls the `remove()` function, supplying the `ul`'s ID as an argument.
- So when you generate the `ul`, you must give the `ul` this same ID: `<ul id="id#1">`.
- In this example it's all literal strings, but naturally you'd have to generate a unique ID using javascript (from your code I can see you're familiar with this principle).

  - I would just use a variable `var idNum` to store the number, starting with `0`.
  - And when you create a new `<ul>`, do this `'<ul id="id#'+idNum+'">'`.
    *(I don't know exactly how you have set up the creation code, but you get the point; you insert the variable `idNum` into the ID-string.)*
  - And at the end of your add-function, you increase the ID-num: `idNum++;`. That way, every `<ul>` has a unique ID.

But as I said, this is really not optimal, because now you have to put that function-call inside your HTML, you need a global variable to store the ID-num, you need to give the ul's an ID when really it's not necessary... A lot of extra code and memory usage that clouds up your script.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it works for the first ul which is not generated but for the rest on click remove doesn't work it just submits.I used e.preventDefault() but only works on first ul, any idea why?

Comment: I revised my answer, I changed `$(".remove_station").click(function(){` to `$("#station").on("click",".remove_station",function(){` (delegated event). This should fix the issue, explanation is in the answer. Let me know if you're still having problems.